# Django, Redis and channels: Using websockets to pass message to browser page via GET request for notifications

Tags: django, websocket, redis, django-channels

I am trying to set up some async notifications in my django app using redis and channels, and new to websockets!

I'm confused why my consumer methods are being called in a specific order (below). My setup is essentially a proof of principle one, where in a get request of a view i send a message to my websocket and i'm trying to retrieve this in the console of browser when i access the page.

The end goal being to do this in some post requests instances, such as account activation or data upload - to notify specific users about these events.

So when i access my view via get request the consumer methods are called in this order:

1. receive
2. disconnect
3. connect

I thought they would be called in this order:

1. connect
2. receive
3. disconnect

What happens in my browser as well, is the first time i access the get request page, websocket opens (with a print to console saying open)
Then if i were to refresh that page, just before the page reloads, the message is printed to console in this case:  HELLO YES THIS IS DOG - but when the page actually refreshes, it disappears. I guess i'm trying to get the websocket to open and receive the message to the console any time the page is accessed (and then i can think about how to add javascript to display this on  my webpage)

django trace log:

```
    INFO runserver.py:164; 2024-01-18 10:20:37: WebSocket CONNECT /ws/notifications/ [192.168.59.164:52021]
    INFO filtering_views.py:171; 2024-01-18 10:20:45: FilterSearchView() GET request

    HELLOOO
    /filtering/

    ----- receive ------

    HELLO YES THIS IS DOG
    user_1

    ----- send_message ------

    HTTP GET /filtering/ 200 [0.06, 192.168.59.164:52015]
    INFO runserver.py:147; 2024-01-18 10:20:45: HTTP GET /filtering/ 200 [0.06, 192.168.59.164:52015]
    WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/notifications/ [192.168.59.164:52021]
    INFO runserver.py:166; 2024-01-18 10:20:45: WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/notifications/ [192.168.59.164:52021]

    ----- disconnect ------

    WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/notifications/ [192.168.59.164:52026]
    INFO runserver.py:168; 2024-01-18 10:20:45: WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/notifications/ [192.168.59.164:52026]

    ----- connect ------

    user_1
    WebSocket CONNECT /ws/notifications/ [192.168.59.164:52026]
    INFO runserver.py:164; 2024-01-18 10:20:45: WebSocket CONNECT /ws/notifications/ [192.168.59.164:52026]
```

consumers.py

```
class NotificationConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):

        print('\n----- connect ------\n')
        user_id = self.scope['user'].id
        # print(self.scope)
        self.group_name = f"user_{user_id}"
        print(self.group_name)
        try:
            await self.channel_layer.group_add(
                self.group_name,
                self.channel_name
            )
            await self.accept()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)


    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        print('\n----- disconnect ------\n')
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.group_name,
            self.channel_name,
        )

    async def receive(self, data_dict):
        print('\n----- receive ------\n')
        text_data = data_dict['message']
        print(text_data)
        print(self.group_name)

        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.group_name,
            {
                'type': 'send_message',
                'message': text_data
            },
        )


    async def send_message(self, event):
        print('\n----- send_message ------\n')
        message = event['message']

        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({'message': message}))
```

base.html

```
<script>
  const socket = new WebSocket(
    
    "ws://" 
    + window.location.host
    + "/ws/notifications/"
    );

  socket.onopen = function(event) {
    console.log("WebSocket connection opened:", event);
  };

  socket.onmessage = (event) => {
        const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
        console.log('Received message:', data.message);
    };


  socket.onclose = function(event) {
    console.log("WebSocket connection closed:", event);
  };

  socket.onerror = (error) => {
    console.error('WebSocket error:', error);
  };

  
</script>
```

results/filtering_views.py

```
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer
class FilterSearchView(AuthMixin, View, HILISQuery):

    template_name = os.path.join('results', 'filter_templates',
                                 'filtering_panel_selection.html')

    login_url = '/'
    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'
    group_required = ['filter']
    raise_exception = True

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        # get context data
        self.context = {}

        channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
        try:
            async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
                f'user_{request.user.id}',
                {
                    'type': 'receive',
                    'message': 'HELLO YES THIS IS DOG'
                }
            )
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

        return render(request, self.template_name, self.context)
```

Am i missing something on the theory of how websockets work? Any help would be greatly appreciated!